# Prevent Infinite loop canActivate Angular Guard

Tags: angular

In order to avoid an infinite loop in my canActivate guard, I added if conditions to check if the route is equal to the desired route, as you can see in the code below.
I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

`guard :`

```js
export class WelcomeGuard implements CanActivate {
    countUserBookings$ = this.store.select<number>(ShipmentSelectors.nbUserBookings);

    constructor(private router: Router, private store: Store) {}

    canActivate(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<UrlTree | boolean> {
        return this.store.dispatch(new CountUserBookings()).pipe(
            switchMap(() => this.countUserBookings$),
            map((nbUserBookings) => {
                if (nbUserBookings === 0) {
                    if (!state.url.includes('welcome')) {
                        return this.router.createUrlTree(['welcome', 'welcome']);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                if (nbUserBookings >= 1 && nbUserBookings <= 10) {
                    if (!state.url.includes('intermediate')) {
                        return this.router.createUrlTree(['welcome', 'intermediate']);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                if (!state.url.includes('dashboard')) {
                    {
                        return this.router.createUrlTree(['welcome', 'dashboard']);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            })
        );
    }
}
```

`router :`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: WelcomeComponent,
        canActivate: [WelcomeGuard],
        children: [
            { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomePageComponent },
            { path: 'intermediate', component: WelcomeIntermediateComponent },
            { path: 'dashboard', component: WelcomeDashboardComponent },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
        ],
    },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

the state contains the URL, so in my code I skip all the time the URL hasn't changed.

the basic premise is that the overall function needs to return true or false in some way, either as a boolean or an observable, when the whole canActivate function returns true the route loads or false it does not. I'm using angular 15, which is different from your code, should still be able to make use of 'skipwhile' maybe to check if authenicated, you might need to put the skipwhile as the first item (above switchmap).

```
.pipe(
skipWhile() => {
   return this.previousState?.url == state.url; //skips whilst this is true 
}),
map((nbUserBookings) => {
   this.previousState = state;
   ....
   //somewhere below this line, you need some code that either returns true or false
```

in angular <= 14 I use

```
skipWhile(isAuthenticated => {
    return isAuthenticated === null || !this.serverEnvironment.loaded
  }),
```

the principle is the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I tried your code and it's not working. I might be doing something wrong but I have a blank page

Comment: @FeckNeck, I've updated my answer to hopefully help more.

Comment: *(...) I might be doing something wrong** imo this is the case as you do redirects from guards that guards those subject of redirections.

Answer (score 0):

U wrote:

> (...) I might be doing something wrong

And IMO this is the case as you do redirects from guards that guards those redirections.

Move that complicated part of your logic into separate service, invoke it when needed (when user enters the app??) and in guards only confirm that user is allowed to visit given path (if that is even needed).

To be clear, it is not invalid to do redirections in guards, but it is just bad in your case.